# How to remove Ubuntu w/ Gnome and put on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-gnome

It saddens me to even have to ask this. But I'm getting serious about making music and Linux doesn't support the music softwares I'm familiar with.

My laptop previously had Windows 8 on it, but I wiped it of Windows and installed Ubuntu with Gnome desktop environment. I'd like to have Windows 7? But I'm not sure how to get it nor how to wipe my computer of Linux. I wouldn't be opposed to duel booting!

Answer (score 1):

not sure how to mark this as a duplicate, but it's a common question.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) for the answer